# How to Display Boolean Value?

Tags: java

```
public static boolean isValidElement(String token) {
    int a1 = 214;
    if(a1 >= 0 && a1 <= 255){
        return true;
    }
    else

        return false;
    System.out.println(isValidElement); 

}
```

This is my code, im just not sure how to display the boolean result of true in this configuration. Im a bit new to java. 
Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: Seems like the `token` variable isn't even used in this context. Wherever you call the `isValidElement(String token)` method, put a `System.out.println(isValidElement(token));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your both `if` and `else` part have `return` statements. It means that the pointer will return from this function on either one `return` statement and so it wont ever reach your `System.out.println()` statement.

Instead, you should write your `System.out.println()` before return statement.

Here's the code,

```
public static boolean isValidElement(String token) {
    int a1 = 214;
    if(a1 >= 0 && a1 <= 255){
        System.out.println(true); 
        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.println(false);  
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

print the result before the return....

```
public static boolean isValidElement(String token) {
    int a1 = 214;
    if(a1 >= 0 && a1 <= 255){
        System.out.println(true); 
        return true;
    }else{
        System.out.println(false);  
        return false;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Might help you a bit.

```
public static boolean isValid() {
    int a1 = 214;
    return (a1 >= 0 && a1 <= 255) ? true : false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // example 1 - just prints the boolean
    int a1 = 214;
    System.out.println(a1 >= 0 && a1 <= 255);

    // example 2 - prints the result of the method call
    System.out.println(isValid());

}
```

Or, if you are after a debugging statement in your implementation then maybe.

```
public static boolean isValid() {
    int a1 = 214;
    boolean res = (a1 >= 0 && a1 <= 255) ? true : false;
    System.out.println(res);
    return res;
}
```